# Substracting two timestamps(0) in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two fields TICKET_TTR_START_DTT , TICKET_TTR_STOP_DTT , Both are defined as TIMESTAMP(0)

Basically i want to know the difference between these two fields

select (TICKET_TTR_START_DTT  -  TICKET_TTR_STOP_DTT)

Example:

Select (2008-08-28 05:24:31  - '2008-08-30 05:24:31')

Output should be in hours and seconds like from above the output is  48 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the difference is less than 10,000 hours:

```
select TICKET_TTR_START_DTT - TICKET_TTR_STOP_DTT HOUR(4) TO SECOND(0)
```